# Dynamic Long Lat Google Maps embed in Ionic 3

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, embed, ionic-native

i am a beginner in ionic 3
I am trying to embed a Google map on my ionic 3 with dynamic long lat using Json
but I had trouble and got an error
Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

this my code :

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" 
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_API_KEY&q={{det.latlong}}" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

How do you make it work?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use gmaps in ionic with the next cordova plugin:

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

It will allow to use gmaps native on the devices and use the web version for desktop. Then you can manipulate the camera, position... with the gmap instance.

Answer (score 0):

The unsafe warnings are there for obvious security reasons. Just use the sanitizer to make the unsafe warnings go away. Here’s a simple tutorial:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/add-video-unsafe-url/88475/9